# How to launch a new tab in incognito mode using selenium java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How to launch a new tab in incognito mode using selenium java?
Getting following error:

```
"code":-32000,"message":"Failed to open new tab - no browser is open"
```

I'm using this code:

```java
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code seems to work only when the `driver` is NOT initiated with `incognito=new`.

```
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
```

If you want your `driver` to be in INCOGNITO mode and want to open a new TAB, you can achieve it using Robot class as below:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("incognito=new");
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.url.com");
        
Robot rb = new Robot();
// Press control keyboard key
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
// Press T keyboard key
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_T);
// Release control keyboard key
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
// Release T keyboard key
rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_T);
```

**Warning:** This solution using Robot class may not work in `headless` mode.